# BroadcastReceiver onReceive() not Called when registered dynamically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, google-glass, google-gdk

The function "onReceive" is called when BroadcastReceiver is Registered in the Manifest but  **NOT** called if registered dynamically.

The code that works is below:

```
public class EyeGesture extends BroadcastReceiver {
    //Eye Gesture
    private static IntentFilter eyeGestureIntent;
    private static Context eyeGestureContext;
    private static StringBuilder gestureInfo = null;
    private static BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

   // public void startEyeListening() {
        //Eye Gesture

    //}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // this = context;
        if (intent.getStringExtra("gesture").equals("WINK")) {
            Log.e("WINKED ","");
        }else {
            Log.e("SOMETHING", "is detected " + intent.getStringExtra("gesture"));
        }
        //Disable Camera Snapshot
       // abortBroadcast();

    }

    public void stopEyeListening() {
        eyeGestureContext.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        eyeGestureIntent = null;
        eyeGestureContext = null;
        gestureInfo = null;
    }

}
```

Below is the Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.inno.inno.glassplugin" >

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainFunct"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_glass_logo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_funct" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger" />
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.inno.inno.glassplugin.EyeGesture">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.EYE_GESTURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem is that "onReceive" is **NOT** called when registered dynamically. I have to do this in a dynamic way. 
Below is the code that is **NOT** working code.

```
public class EyeGesture extends Activity {
    //Eye Gesture
    IntentFilter eyeGestureIntentFilter;
    Context eyeGestureContext;
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;


    public  EyeGesture(){
        Log.e("CONSTRUCTOR ", "");
        eyeGestureContext = MainFunct.getCurrentContext();
        eyeGestureIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.google.glass.action.EYE_GESTURE");
        eyeGestureIntentFilter.setPriority(1000);
        startRunning();
    }

    void startRunning(){
        eyeGestureContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.e("Received ", " Something");
            }
        },eyeGestureIntentFilter);
    }


    @Override
    public  void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public  void  onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
    public void stopEyeListening() {
        eyeGestureContext.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        eyeGestureIntentFilter = null;
        eyeGestureContext = null;
    }

}
```

Also, I don't want to extend BroadcastReceiver from this class. Why am I not receiving anything if registered dynamically. I also removed the following line from the Manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.inno.inno.glassplugin.EyeGesture">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.EYE_GESTURE" />
                </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

but still, it is not working. There is no error or exception thrown.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What output do you get in the LogCat when registered dynamically?

Comment: Same issue with me. Looks like no one has a clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using explicit intent? It seems that dynamically registered broadcast receivers cannot receive explicit intents. Implicit intents work.
For reference: http://streamingcon.blogspot.com/2014/04/dynamic-broadcastreceiver-registration.html

If the issue is not explicit intents but if you are using LocalBroadcastManager for sendBroadcast then make sure that the registerReceiver is also called of LocalBroadcastManager and not of Context

Answer (score 1):

Try using ApplicationContext instead of Activity.

Modyifing line:

```
eyeGestureContext = MainFunct.getCurrentContext();
```

I would try things in this order:

1. `eyeGestureContext = getApplicationContext();`
2. `eyeGestureContext = getApplication();`

If above does not work I would extend the Application and do:

```
public class MyExtendedApplication extends Application {

    private static MyExtendedApplication instance;

    public static MyExtendedApplication getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

This works for me with global "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" broadcast

```
Context c = MyExtendedApplication.getInstance();
c.registerReceiver(
        connectivtyChangedReceiver,
        connectivityFilter);
```

so should also for you with "com.google.android.glass.action.EYE_GESTURE"

Answer (score 0):

Watching adb logcat in XE21.3, it looks like com.google.android.glass.action.EYE_GESTURE intent never hits the event bus; instead, it skips straight to com.google.glass.action.TAKE_PICTURE, which is the same intent as the camera button. So it looks like the eye-gesture API was removed without announcement.

Comment: It works if registered via Manifest but not when registered in a dynamically way with Context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver();

That's not the problem. Thanks for helping

Answer (score -1):

- The receiver should extend the BroadcastReceiver class.
- Define the receiver in the manifest
- In the code (maybe onCreate), register the receiver

  - Create a receiver object
  - Define the intent filters
  - call RegisterReceiver() passing in the receiver and the intent filters

Comment: how is this helping the OP? They posted specific code.